# How to do a git checkout when VisualStudio is using a dll in the package folder?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am using Git on Visual Studio 2015. When I build the solution and then try to check out a branch, **the operation fails and Visual Studio displays the following message** :

> An error occurred. Detailed message: Could not remove
>   'C:/Workspaces/[SolutionName]/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.0.1/tools/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll':
>   Access denied.

- The packages folder is added in the `.gitignore` file
- Global static analysis is disabled
- **If I close Visual Studio, I am able to do a git checkout from the command prompt.**

I've found that the MSBuild.exe process is using the above-mentioned file when I build the solution. When I try to delete it after that, I get a popup saying that it is used by Visual Studio (which must be devenv.exe).

I've tried to enable [sparse-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#_sparse_checkout) in the core repository settings and exclude the `package` folder but without any effect.

**How can I checkout branches from Visual Studio without this error?**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have the packages folder in the git repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try forcing Git to untrack the packages folder

```
git rm -r --cached packages/
git commit -am "Untrack the packages folder"
```

It sounds to me like the packages folder is being tracked by Git despite being in the .gitignore file.  This can happen if the packages folder was added to .gitignore *after* it was already being tracked or if the .gitignore file was added to the project after Git started tracking the folder.  Either way, Git is trying to remove one or more files in the folder during checkout and Visual Studio wants to keep them.

Comment: That was exactly the issue. I did not notice that the packages folder was still present on some branches, resulting in this weird behavior. As I'm using Azure DevOps, I just deleted the folder and committed.